# How to uninstall Rapiddrive Driver from Lenovo Y470

Tags: windows-7, laptop, ssd

I bought a Lenovo Y470 laptop last week with high configuration such as i7 2G processor, 8Gb ram, 1Gb Nvidia Graphics, 750Gb HDD.

I updated the drivers from [Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/). Unfortunately I installed the Rapiddrive driver although my laptop doesn't have an SSD feature. After I installed the Rapiddrive driver, the system got slower.

I tried to do Factory Restore but it didn't work. I have tried asking the Lenovo support for three days in their forum, but no replies.

Can anyone help me in uninstalling the Rapiddrive Driver from Windows 7?